# Parsing Json from server

Tags: java, android, json

How can i parse json like this:

```
{"SizeOptions": [
{
  "Name": "دور باسن",
  "GroupSizeId": 2,
  "Id": 5,
  "LangId": 0
},
{
  "Name": "دور کمر",
  "GroupSizeId": 2,
  "Id": 6,
  "LangId": 0
} ],"SizeValues": [
{
  "Value": "a",
  "SizeId": 11,
  "SizeOptionId": 5,
  "ProductId": 1069,
  "Id": 145627,
  "LangId": 0
},
{
  "Value": "a",
  "SizeId": 11,
  "SizeOptionId": 8,
  "ProductId": 1069,
  "Id": 145630,
  "LangId": 0
}  ],"Sizes": [
{
  "Name": "XXL",
  "GroupSizeId": 2,
  "Id": 11,
  "LangId": 0
},
{
  "Name": "L",
  "GroupSizeId": 2,
  "Id": 12,
  "LangId": 0
}]}
```

I want to put all of Names in "SizeOptions" in diffrent Strings(String name1,name2,name3)

i tried this for getting started :

```
 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONObject p = jObject.getJSONObject("SizeOptions");
 String name = p.getString("Name");
```

but it's just giving me a "Null" value!
what's its problem? how can i fix it? Please Help

Comment: `SizeOptions` is an Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONSONArray p = jObject.getJSONArray("SizeOptions");

for(int i=0;i<p.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jObjectValue=p.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jObjectValue.getString("Name");
}
```

Comment: I had to look it up and it is true that JSONArray in the android sdk API is not iterable. Such a poor API.

Comment: @AluanHaddad alternative is you can use GSON lib with custom object and pojo

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a JSONArray as JSONObject. Try the following:

```
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray p = jObject.getJSONArray("SizeOptions");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo = p.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jo.getString("Name");
        names.add(name);
    }

    System.out.println(names);
```